# How to stop Jupyter outputting truncated results when using pd.Series.value_counts()?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a `DataFrame` and I want to display the frequencies for certain values in a certain `Series` using `pd.Series.value_counts()`.

The problem is that I only see truncated results in the output. I'm coding in Jupyter Notebook.

I have tried unsuccessfully a couple of methods:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(...) # assume df is a DataFrame with many columns and rows

# 1st method
df.col1.value_counts()

# 2nd method
print(df.col1.value_counts())

# 3rd method
vals = df.col1.value_counts()
vals  # neither print(vals) doesn't work

# All output something like this
value1         100000
value2         10000
...
value1000      1
```

Currently this is what I'm using, but it's quite cumbersome:

```
print(df.col1.value_counts()[:50])
print(df.col1.value_counts()[50:100])
print(df.col1.value_counts()[100:150])
# etc.
```

Also, I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38565985/value-counts-giving-truncated-results) related Stack Overflow question, but haven't found it helpful.

So how to stop outputting truncated results?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to print all rows:

```
pd.options.display.max_rows = 1000
print(vals)
```

If you want to print all rows only once:

```
with pd.option_context("display.max_rows", 1000):
    print(vals)
```

Relevant documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html).

Answer (score 4):

I think you need [`option_context`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.option_context.html) and set to some large number, e.g. 999. Advatage of [solution](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#getting-and-setting-options) is:

> **option_context context manager** has been exposed through the top-level API, allowing you to execute code with given option values. Option values are restored automatically when you exit the with block.

```
#temporaly display 999 rows
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', 999):
    print (df.col1.value_counts())
```